# How to get all names for a sql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having issue getting all of the names of people and whether they play rugby or not.

If they play then display `Yes` otherwise `No`. At the moment I am just getting a single result of a person who plays rugby not others who did not. Can anyone help me?

Current SQL:

```
select P1.name, case when S.sport = 'rugby' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as rugby
    from Persons P1, 
         Persons  P2, 
         SportTogether S
    where P1.id = S.personA_id 
      and P2.id = S.personB_id
      and S.sport = 'rugby'
    group by case when S.sport = 'rugby' then 'Yes' else 'No' end;
```

Comment: @ADyson How to use left join here where persons id is using in two columns in SportTogether table. I have used left join but I was getting redundant values even using distinct key word

Comment: It's possible you need two separate joins onto the SportTogether table. But it would be easier to solve if you show us the table schemas, some sample data from the tables, and a sample of the expected result. Merely showing us a query which doesn't work only gives us half the info. Remember we are not looking over your shoulder and we know exactly nothing about your database, except what you tell us.

Comment: @ADyson sure I am editing my question, please give me a sec. Thanks

Comment: `from SportTogether S left join Persons P1 on S.personA_id=P1.id left join Persons P2 on S.personB_id=P2.id where S.sport = 'rugby'`  (on how to use left join)

Comment: @tnavidi I have used this one before but I was getting single value as well.

Comment: We still need a sample of the expected result as well please.

Comment: @ADyson output should contain the names of all people and the columns rugby there should contain "yes" or "not" depending whether this person plays rugby or not

Comment: As requested, just provide an exact example of the required output please. It's a lot easier for everyone and removes any potential ambiguity arising from descriptions.

Comment: Where and when did you learn this join syntax? It is a syntax we used in the 1980s before explicit joins made it into standard SQL in 1992. That was even before the first version of MySQL existed. Please use explicit joins (`[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion you are using a wrong approach. You want to select persons, so select from the persons table. You want to know whether a person plays rugby, so look up persons in the rugby table. Lookups can be done with `IN` or `EXISTS`.

```
select
  name,
  case when exists 
  (
    select null 
    from sporttogether s
    where s.sport = 'rugby'
    and p.id in (s.persona_id, s.personb_id)
  ) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as plays_rugby
from persons p
order by name;
```